# Testing focusElement in angular 2 with karma+jasmine

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

How to write correct test in angular 2 with karma + jasmine for this public:

```
public focusElement(element: HTMLElement, event: Event): void {
    element.focus();
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

I start with this:

```
describe("LoginComponent", () => {
    describe("function focusElement(): void", () => {
        let testLoginComponent: LoginComponent;
        beforeEach(() => {
            testLoginComponent = new LoginComponent(null, null);
        });
        // test 
        });
    });
});
```

But i really understand how to write correct test for this func.